# C - Pointer & Reference

Tags: c, pointers

I'm studying computer science and try out C programming language in my spare time. Beside I use this book for a better understanding: **Computer Systems: A programmer's perspective**. It gives some example codes in C aswell.

So, i wrote a code with some pointers - like this: `int *x`. And I'm still struggling with pointers and references - though I think I understand it.

So I wrote a little Script and experimented with pointers and references.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int *x;
        printf("Pointer: %p\n", x);
        printf("Value int: %d\n", *x);
        printf("Pointer ref: %p\n", &x);
}
```

Output in bash / terminal:

```
Pointer: 0x7ffe99ea7420
Value int: 1
Pointer ref: 0x7ffe99ea7330
```

(Setup: Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 )

Now i was a little bit confused, that a non-initialized variable `x` has the value 1 - and that the Pointer and Reference is point to a memory address.
In my first semester at the university I have learned Java and also understand how the JVM and the Stack works.
So I assume that it is the same in C. The compiler allocated some memory for each object in code. But why is the Value of `x` **1**.

Maybe someone would be so nice and would explain it to me.
I'm also very grateful for any links for further reading or some exchange of knowledge.

Comment: References don't exist in C. `&x` is a pointer to `x`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Thank you all for fast and suitable answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninitialized variables have unspecified values. It is **undefined behavior** to read them before they are assigned. Therefore the `x` and `*x` expressions are **undefined behavior**.

Very roughly, undefined behavior means that anything can happen and that your code is broken. This is covered in any beginner C book.

Comment: Ok, this explains a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Note it's safe to read an uninitialised char, signed char, or unsigned char.

Comment: @Bathsheba can you please explain or give a link?

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
int *x;
```

`x` is integer pointer, *pointer should point to valid memory location* but in your case it's uninitialized. Hence `de-referencing(*x)` uninitialized pointer causes `undefined behavior` i.e any thing can happen, it may crash.

So answer of this

```
printf("Value int: %d\n", *x);
```

is **undefined behavior** since **x** doesn't have any valid memory location.

And here

```
printf("Pointer ref: %p\n", &x);
```

you are simply *printing address of pointer variable* `x`, there is no concept of **reference** in **C**.

**Edit :-** From  [C standard n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **3.4.3**
>
> 1 **undefined behavior** behavior, upon use of a nonportable or
>   erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this
>   International Standard imposes no requirements.
>
> **Section** **6.7** **Declarations**
>
> ```
> double *dp;
>
> *dp = 42; // undefined behavior
> ```

An uninitialized pointer doesn't point anywhere. It is illegal to de-reference it.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. That helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pointer: 0x7ffe99ea7420
Value int: 1
Pointer ref: 0x7ffe99ea7330
```

This output is a subset of `undefined` behavior set. The output you are getting may change when you execute the code various times.

In the code you have not initialized `int *x;`, hence it will have unspecified values. And all 3 of the following statements are called on an un-initialized variable hence output of each of them is `undefined`

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n", x);
printf("Value int: %d\n", *x);
```

However

```
printf("Pointer ref: %p\n", &x);
```

will print the address of the x.

Comment: `&x` is well defined. It is the valid address of an uninitialized pointer to int. You can use it to assign a value to the underlying pointer: `*(&x) = /* x = */ NULL;`

Comment: Right except to that of printf("Pointer ref: %p\n", &x);. Correct the answer.